# Why Shift R doesn't work properly?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

When I am trying to use Shift + R (repeat action) after rotation, it works in the wrong direction. Why is this happening?

[image: bug]

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. I've tried a few things to try and re-create the behavior and I can't find a way so far...

Comment: I also tried to reproduce this problem, but it works correctly. Shift R is rotating in the right direction.

Comment: What version of your Blender? Maybe you can use another build? There is a similar report from developers of this problem as seen in this link (see video): https://developer.blender.org/T76919.

Comment: This bug appears only in the last version (2.92). I installed 2.91.2 build and now it works properly